# Can this binomial polynomial sum be simplified?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} k^d$$

where $d$ is some fixed positive integer. Is this a well known sum that has a faster-than-$O(n)$ evaluation? It looks similar to Faulhaber's formula, except with binomial coefficients.

Comment: d! times the coefficient of x^d in [1+exp(x)]^n

Comment: @CountIblis How/Why so?

Comment: Replace k^d by exp(k x) and calculate the summation. Then if you expand the function in series you see that inside the summation the coefficient x^d will be k^d/d!

Comment: It turns out this is a duplicate as seen at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355262/). I did the calculation anyway because it was faster than searching for and finding the previous post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$S_d(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k^d.$$
using
$$k^d =
\frac{d!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{d+1}} \exp(kz) \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{d!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{d+1}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \exp(kz) 
\; dz
\\ = \frac{d!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{d+1}} 
(1+\exp(z))^n
\; dz
\\ = \frac{d!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{d+1}} 
(2+\exp(z)-1)^n
\; dz
\\ = \frac{d!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{d+1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} 2^{n-q} (\exp(z)-1)^q
\; dz
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} 2^{n-q} 
\times q! \times {d\brace q}$$

for a final answer of
$$\sum_{q=0}^d {n\choose q} 2^{n-q} 
\times q! \times {d\brace q}.$$

This is a polynomial of degree $d$ in $n.$

The change  of the upper  limit is justified  as follows: if  $n\gt d$
then the Stirling number is zero for $n\ge q \gt d$ and we may replace
$n$ by $d$. On the other  hand if $n\lt d$ the binomial coefficient is
zero for $n\lt q\le d$ and we may again replace $n$ by $d.$

Here we have used the species equation for labeled set partitions
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

which gives the bivariate  generating function of the [Stirling numbers
of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $$\exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

Answer (score 1):

For $d=1,2,3$, the results are $2^{n-1}n$, $2^{n-2}n(n+1)$ and $2^{n-3}n^2(n+3)$
respectively. For higher values $d$, experiment with [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28k%3D0%2Cn%2Cbinom%28n%2Ck%29*k%5E4%29)  to find a pattern.

Note, that for $d>3$ you need the generalized hypergeometric function.