# General formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n k^a \binom{n}{k}$ is somehow hypergeometric?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

## Original question is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923115/sums-sum-k-0n-kt-n-choose-k-where-t-is-a-positive-integer). Please refer to after the edit

---

**Original question:**

I was investigating formulas of the form
$\sum_{k=0}^n k^a \binom{n}{k}$ after noticing on Wikipedia that $\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k} = n2^{n-1}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2 \binom{n}{k} = (n+n^2)2^{n-2}$.

Wolfram Alpha notes that for $a=3$, $\sum_{k=0}^n k^3 \binom{n}{k} = n^2 (n + 3)2^{n-3}$ but for $a=4,5$ then switches to $\sum_{k=0}^n k^4 \binom{n}{k} = n\ _4 F_3(2, 2, 2, 1 - n;1, 1, 1;-1)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n k^5 \binom{n}{k} = n\ _5 F_4(2, 2, 2, 2, 1 - n;1, 1, 1, 1;-1)$.

My conjecture is that, in general, $$\sum_{k=0}^n k^a \binom{n}{k} = n\ _a F_{a-1}(2, 2, ..., 2, 1 - n;1, 1, ..., 1; -1)$$
Which is *some* kind of polynomial since one of the numerators there is non-positive (and I suspect Wolfram Alpha just spat this function out so as to avoid calculating the polynomial outright), but I don't know how to use this function for computing with a given $n$ and $a$ (though I begin to suspect there isn't an easy way to do so).

I'm also wondering if there's a formula at all for $\sum_{k=0}^n k^n \binom{n}{k}$.

Any suggestions or advice welcome.

---

### EDIT

Since my original question already has an answer, I'd like to pivot to asking how the resulting identity works.
$$\begin{align}
\newcommand{\stirtwo}[2]{\left\{{#1}\atop{#2}\right\}}
\sum_{k=0}^n k^a \binom{n}{k}
&= n\ _a F_{a-1}(2, 2, ..., 2, 1 - n;1, 1, ..., 1; -1)\\
&=2^{n-m}\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{n}{j}2^{m-j}\stirtwo{m}{j}j!\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Check these: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1400588/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/923115/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/355262/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%20k%5Ea%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%24)

Comment: If $p_a(x)=x(x-1)\cdots(x-a+1),$ the "falling factorial," then $\sum_{k=0}^n p_a(k)\binom nk=p_a(n)2^{n-a}.$ So you really to to write $x^a$ in the basis $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_a$ to find your result. So $x^3=x(x-1)(x-2)+3x(x-1)+x$ gives $$\sum k^3\binom nk=(n(n-1)(n-2)+6n(n-1)+4n)2^{n-3}$$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think that answers the main question, though I am still curious on how the hypergeometric function relates to the Stirling numbers of the second kind answer

Comment: @Sherlock9: Your conjecture is sound. I just wanted to add a corresponding answer, but regrettably this post has been closed.

Comment: @epi163sqrt Sorry, I didn't realize "private feedback" meant closing the question as a duplicate. Just edited the question and I hope to have it reopened soon.

Comment: Please do not change the question just to avoid closure. If you have a new question, ask it as one.

Comment: @Nij Sorry. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n k^n \binom{n}{k}$$ is sequence $A072034$ in $OEIS$

Vaclav Kotesovec proposed a superb approximation
$$S_n \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)}}\left(\frac{n}{e\, W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)}\right)^n$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.